# Access Object1 methods from a returned Object

Tags: java, object

I have to make a list of objects, `Object1`, `Object2`, `Object3`.

```
class Object1 {
    private String str;
    private double num;
    
    public Object1(...){
    ...
    }

    public double getNum(){
        return this.num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(" String: %s, Number %.2f", this.str, this.num);
    }

}
```

In order to do this I created another class `Item` which, depending on the input of the constructor, initializes either `Object1` or `Object2` and so on and instantiate an `access()` method that returns said object.

```
class Item{
    private Object item;
    
    public Item(String str, double num){
        item = new Object1(str, num);
    }

    public Item(String str, double num, int num1){
        item = new Object2(str, num, num1);
    }

    ...

    public Object access(){
        return item;
    }
}
```

In the Main if I access the item `toString` it gives back the right output, but I cannot access any other methods of `Object1` etc.

```
print(list.get(i).access().toString());

>>> String: Something, Number: 99.92

print("" + list.get(i).access().getNum());

>>> Cannot resolve method getNum() in Object
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Do you understand [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) is a class pre-defined in Java?

Comment: The real answer here is: the compiler **only** knows that the `item` in your Item class is of type **Object**. Go lookup the javadoc for java.lang.Object and check for the methods that you find in there. The compiler doesn't know that AT RUNTIME, that `item` refers to this or that specific other class. So the real point here is: you should do a bit of research on the java type system, and how everything is a subclass of Object somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that this is an Object1, you can cast it, like

```
print("" + ((Object1)list.get(i).access()).getNum());
```

If you don't know it's an Object1, you can use instanceof

```
if (list.get(i).access() instanceof Object1) {
  ...
}
```

Finally, in the case where you know nothing, there is a way introspect an Object's methods

```
list.get(i).access().getClass().getMethods();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 17, you can try this (with preview being activated):

```
…
switch( list.get( i ).access() )
{
  case Object1 object1 -> object1.getNum();
  case Object2 object2 -> object2. … // whatever method fits …
  case Object3 object3 -> object3. …
  case null -> throw new Error( "access() returned null" );
  default -> throw new Error( "No clue what accessed() returned …";
}
```

The keyword here is "pattern matching for switch", and I think it is a nice feature to solve problems like yours – although I personally prefer to avoid such designs whenever possible.